# jQuery scan UL structure for all items with certain class

Tags: jquery, traversal

I have a ul>li structure similar to the following:

```
<ul id="node">
    <li><a data-name="One">One</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a data-name="Two">Two</a></li>
            <li><a class="me" data-name="Three">Three</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a data-name="Four">Four</a></li>
                    <li><a class="me" data-name="Five">Five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My need is to traverse this and grab the data-name attribute from each `<a>` element with the class me, which would result in an array:

```
items = {"Three","Five"}
```

**NEW ISSUE:**

What if I wanted to start at `Three`, only knowing that the `data-name` attribute to traverse from is `Three` and only traversing down from there - i.e. the result would only be `Five`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = $('ul#node a.me').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('data-name');
});
```

or

```
var items = [];
$('ul#node a.me').each(function(){
   items.push($(this).data('name'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/dvAmj/)

**NEW ISSUE :**

```
var items = [];
$('ul#node a[data-name="Three"]').parent().children().find('a.me').each(function(){
    items.push($(this).data('name'));
});
```

And [the new Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/fGEPs/)...

Comment: I would use $(this).data("name")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method.

```
var items = $('ul a.me').map(function(){
    return this.dataset.name
}).get()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGMSw/

Comment: +1 Just don't forget though to call items.get() to get the *actual* array.

Comment: @aquinas Thanks, I had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.me').each (function () { alert ( $(this).attr('data-name')); } );
```